# Poincare map of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the following equations

\begin{cases} 
    \dot x = - x - y + \cos t,\\
    \dot y = x - y + \sin t.
\end{cases}

I am looking for Poincaré map for the orbit through $(1,1)$ and the section $\Sigma = \{(s,s)|s>0\}$. I managed to find the general solution for some initial conditions $x_0,y_0$
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\ y 
\end{pmatrix}
= e^{-t}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos t & -\sin t \\ \sin t & \cos t 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x_0-1 \\ y_0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos t \\ \sin t 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

However, I think that for finding the Poincaré map I would have to solve the autonomous equation, while the one I have is non-autonomous.

But autonomous form of that equation is non-homogeneous... right? I am stuck here,
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the exact problem that you want to solve? Because for $T$-perodic non-autonomous systems stroboscopic map is usually more suitable concept. You take the state of the system and map it into the state after time $T$ — a bit natural for periodic forcing.

Comment: The orbit through $(x_0,x_0)=(1,1)$ crosses $\Sigma=\{(x,x)\mid x>0\}$ at $(x_n,x_n)$ at successive times $t_n$ such that $x_n\to\ell$, $y_n\to\ell$, $x_n<\ell<y_n$ with $\ell=1/\sqrt2$. Furthermore, $t_n$ is the unique root of $\tan(t+\frac\pi4)=e^t$ in $(2n\pi,\frac\pi4+2n\pi)$ and $t_n=\frac\pi4+2n\pi+o(1)$. Is this your question?

Answer (score 0):

As the system has many parts corresponding to a rotation in the plane, it can be interesting to explore it as a dynamic in the complex plane. Set $z=x+iy$, then
$$
\dot z=(-1+i)z+e^{it}\\
z=Ae^{(-1+i)t}+Be^{it}\\
B(i+1-i)=1\implies B=1\\
z(0)=1+i=A+1\implies A=i
$$
The task is now to find the points where $\arg(z(t))=\frac\pi4$,
$$
\frac\pi4+2k\pi=\arg(e^{it}(ie^{-t}+1))=t+\arctan(e^{-t})
$$
for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. This is not symbolically solvable, so some kind of approximation is necessary.

For large $t>0$, the inverse tangent will have a value close to zero, so $t=t_k\approx  \frac\pi4+2k\pi$. For large $t<0$, the inverse tangent will be close to $\frac\pi2$, so $t=t_k\approx-\frac{\pi}4+2k\pi$. This approximation should also be good for $k=\pm1$, but the correction to the exact root will be more noticeable.